# Mac install command line tools for xcode with iOS SDK

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-command-line-tools

I'm trying to install the XCode Command Line Tools so that I can build a library for iOS from the command line.

The entire process from installing the tools to building the library needs to be able to run from the command line for automation.

I've managed to get the command line tools installed, however once they're installed, in `/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs` I only have `MacOSX.sdk` and `MacOSX10.13.sdk`.

In order to build the library, I need `iPhoneOS.sdk`, which I cannot figure out how to get installed.

How would I go about doing this while still being able to wrap automation around it?

Comment: "I'm trying to install the XCode Command Line Tools so that I can build a library for iOS from the command line." I've never done that, but could the premise of the question be false? `xcodebuild` does not depend upon the presence of the command line tools. "In order to build the library, I need iPhoneOS.sdk, which I cannot figure out how to get installed" It's inside Xcode, which is what `xcodebuild` uses.

Comment: @matt specifically, I'm building openssl for iOS. There aren't any reliable scripts on github for doing this (they all seem to be broken, outdated or unusable to some extent), so i'm putting together a new one that can be run in a repeatable vagrant environment. From what i've seen so far, when trying to configure and make openssl you get this error: `clang: warning: no such sysroot directory: '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk' [-Wmissing-sysroot]` implying that it requires iPhoneOS.sdk to compile. I might wrong, but i'm unsure where to look next

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is still relevant, but here's where you can find your iPhone SDK. It's not part of the command line tools. It is part of the XCode package.

`/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS.sdk/`